# What's the MacOS equivalent for Ctrl+Shift+V?

Tags: macos, shortcut

If you use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> on Windows, it usually pastes the text from the clipboard without formatting.

Is there an equivalent shortcut for macOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all apps support this (MS Office, I'm looking at you) but many do including Apple's Apps.

Though is not *without* formatting Per Se. It is actually Paste and Match Style and you do it with:

> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>

Comment: In some apps, such as Chrome, it is exactly what you’d expect from familiarity with the Windows shortcut: shift-command-V.

Comment: Yah, like MS Office, there are developers who don't use the system bindings for their own (internal, presumably) reasons. There are likely more apps that 'break' that keybinding as well

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236):

> Option-Shift-Command-V: Paste and Match Style: Apply the style of the surrounding content to the item pasted within that content.

Please note that "The behavior of these shortcuts may vary with the app you're using."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86521/discussion-on-answer-by-dualie-whats-the-macos-equivalent-for-ctrlshiftv).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a particular app that doesn't show that option, you can create a new service using Automator and attribute a different shortcut for that function. Let me know if that is your case.