# How to alway paste WITHOUT formating in MacOs Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina

So i want when i paste some text (Command + V), it always paste as plain text, without any formatting that could exist in the source.

Currently if i copy a text in Word that has bold and italic, when i paste it on another app it will paste with bold and italic. What i want is to paste only the text, without any formatting.

I know i could use another more complicated shortcut to do this, but i want to remap Cmd+V to do this by default.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/49447066/3310334 — if anything from there helps you, answer your own question here

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344252/whats-the-macos-equivalent-for-ctrlshiftv